# How do I connect Unity Components to Visual Studio Code? (the code autofill with unity components)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

So I am really just about starting to code in Unity, and I am only following tutorials on the internet. And on a lot of them, the coders have some sort of autofill that shows the Unity components (KeyCode, Debug.Log, etc.) So, does anyone know how to connect Unity to VS Code that would be helpful.

(I have noticed that the coders use VS 2019, so if I can't use connect VS Code to Unity and I need VS 2019, tell me.)

Thanks! :)

(Also if you don't understand what I am talking about feel free to ask further)

Answer (score 1):

VS Code official site has a lot of instructions about many setups, and here is the one for Unity integration: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity
Sometimes all you need is just type `vs code unity` in Google and hit Enter...

And yeah, you can use VS Code. I use VS Code + Unity setup on Linux and it has pretty much all I need for my little projects. Thanks to great amount of VS Code extensions available and built-in Git support, I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps: [Using VS Tools for Unity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/using-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?pivots=windows)

I don't know if it works with VS code but it might be very similar like VS

Answer (score 0):

Actually thats pretty easy

1. Open your Visual Studio 2019 Installer
2. Click on Change at Visual Studio
3. Under the Bulletpoint "Gaming" enable "Gamedesigne with Unity" and install it
4. Inside Unity go to Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools and set Visual Studio under "External Script Editor"
5. Maybe Restart Unity

I think thas everything you have to do.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm talking about VS CODE.

Comment: Oh my bad ^^. I also tried it with vs code at the beginning and it was pretty bad no auto complete extension has worked for me.. so I switch to vs 2019 and it works absolutely fine